# the packet flow from a network interface to a local process? help!

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I'm read *Linux Iptables Pocket Reference*. So I do not understand the figures presented. It says that packets travel through chains, and are presented to the rules one at a time and in order.

Then for instance there is a figure for input for the corresponding tables and chains. 
- mangle : PREROUTING
- nat : PREROUTING
- mangle : INPUT
- filter : INPUT

I don't really understand. Does this mean that the packet in the mangle state, is presented to a rule, then the same packet goes to the nat table and is presented to a rule, to mangle and a new rule and so on?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I have downloaded the book you mention, but can not figure out which diagram you refer to. My answer is based on a different flow chart diagram, with a link to that diagram.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent iptables flow diagram on @bodizazen's [web site](http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables/).

Yes, packets travserse the iptables "chains" as per the diagram. However, one must keep in mind some special cases. For example, the nat PREROUTING table is only consulted once per "NEW" connection, and thereafter subsequent packets traverse the path forged by the first one.

A very good way to assist with learning iptables is to place logging rules, with unique identifiers, throughout your rule set, so that you get feedback on packet flow through the rule set for differing scenarios. Combine that with using a packet sniffer such as tcpdump or wireshark, to gain furhter insight into what is going on.